# Where do I download mysql bench for mac that supports json entries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My server is running 5.7 but mysql bench doesnt support json fields.  Where do I download a version of mysql workbench that supports this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com

Comment: that only includes the link for mysql 5.6

Comment: MySQL 5.6? That is a server version. Don't you want MySQL Workbench instead? You can get WB 6.3.9 from this location as well.

Comment: yep i understand mysql 5.6 is the server version.  wb 6.3.9 is the one i'm using and it doesn't support 5.7 to add json fields despite my server having mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 (the current version)](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) supports JSON fields editing:

[image]

Use the field editor via the context menu in the resultset grid to open it.